# The file copied by python can not be access by another process

Tags: python, file, copy, shutil

I use python **shuitl.copy2** method to copy some file from a share folder, after copy success there will start a process which need access these copied file. **The question** is sometimes there have a file can not be access by the new process, **Error 32** is reported. My script is running circularly, but the issue does not happen every time. Does any one know what the problem is?

Update some simple code. Specific request trigger the *MyThread* run, after the copy end, another excutable application will use these files and the applicaiton report Error32.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, fileList, destFolder):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):

    for fileItem in self.fileList:
        if self.stop:
            break
        try:
            self.__copyFile(fileItem, localDestFolder)
            self.successList.append(fileItem)
        except Exception, e:
            self.errorList.append((fileItem, str(e)))

@staticmethod
def __copyFile(source, destination):
    print 'Use shutil to copy file %s' % source
    shutil.copy2(source, destination)
    print 'Copy end'
```

Comment: Error 32 by itself is pretty meaningless without knowing how it is reported.   In C it is "broken pipe", which implies it is something other than the file copy at fault.   Please show some code and a full traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The file pointer is probably not closed properly.

Maybe add a little `time.sleep()` between the copy and the start of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried it, but this solution is not work yet. I have tried add some logs to track the copy thread, the logs shows the thread ended normally.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The issue happened because another process created by the parent process during the copy thread coping files. so the file handle of one copied file be passed to the new process, and the new process keeps handle the file handle until it end. So during the process running, the file can not be access by other applications. That's it.